# Hierarchical GAMs - why am I not getting individual results for my categorical variable?

Tags: hierarchical-data, gam

I am trying to do a HGAM in order to separate my large dataset by Reservoir. One of my predictor variables is Season_Y, indicating the season and year it the sample was taken. Here is my code:

```
 model = gam( 
    log1p(GEO) ~ s(Season_Y, by=Res, k=, bs ="fs") +
    t2(TP, TIN.TP, by=Res, bs="fs", k=5) + 
    s(Sil, by=Res, k=5) +
    s(SO4, by=Res, k=5) +
    s(Dfe, by=Res, k=5) +
    s(Ortho, by=Res, k=5) +
    s(NO3.NH3, by=Res, k=5),
  data=gam.data,
  family=Gamma,
  method="REML" 
)
```

Normally in a GLM I get individual scores for each subsequent Season_Y, e.g. Winter_2019. but I only an overall Season_Y score. As displayed below:

```
                                    edf Ref.df         F  p-value    
s(Season_Y):ResAlaw           4.603e+00  6.000 3.091e+02  0.99783    
s(Season_Y):ResAlwen          2.474e+00  5.000 2.085e+03  0.99962    
s(Season_Y):ResCefni          2.600e+00  7.000 1.168e+03  0.99809    
s(Season_Y):ResDolwen         6.863e-05  1.000 4.220e+07  0.99803    
s(Season_Y):ResLlandegfedd    6.795e-05  1.000 1.219e+07  0.99856    
s(Season_Y):ResLlwyn Onn      4.350e+00  6.000 3.917e+01  0.99830    
s(Season_Y):ResPentwyn        1.267e-04  2.000 4.130e+05  0.99996    
s(Season_Y):ResPlas Uchaf     4.798e-02  5.000 2.801e+04  0.99768    
s(Season_Y):ResPontsticill    3.182e+00  7.000 1.672e+01  0.99950
```

When I do `gam.check` I don't get any values:

```
                                   k'      edf k-index p-value    
s(Season_Y):ResAlaw           7.00e+00 4.60e+00      NA      NA    
s(Season_Y):ResAlwen          7.00e+00 2.47e+00      NA      NA    
s(Season_Y):ResCefni          7.00e+00 2.60e+00      NA      NA    
s(Season_Y):ResDolwen         7.00e+00 6.86e-05      NA      NA    
s(Season_Y):ResLlandegfedd    7.00e+00 6.79e-05      NA      NA    
s(Season_Y):ResLlwyn Onn      7.00e+00 4.35e+00      NA      NA    
s(Season_Y):ResPentwyn        7.00e+00 1.27e-04      NA      NA    
s(Season_Y):ResPlas Uchaf     7.00e+00 4.80e-02      NA      NA    
s(Season_Y):ResPontsticill    7.00e+00 3.18e+00      NA      NA
```

Just want a breakdown of how each season from each year is significant, please?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Season_Y` *really* contains data like `"Winter_2019"` you are using the `fs` basis incorrectly. This basis is the equivalent of a random slope, but instead of a linear effect we get a smooth effect for each level of the grouping variable. The critical thing here is that you are producing a smooth (lots of them) so you have to pass it a **continuous** variable and `Season_Y` isn't continuous. If this is even doing anything sensible, it is just creating a random effect (intercept) and hence it would be *much* clearer in terms of the intention of the code to use:

```
s(Season_Y, by = Res, bs = "re")
```

As to why everything is `NA` in the basis dimension check, you asked for random effects and the basis dimension check is not available for those terms. From `?check.k`:

> Currently smooths of factor variables are not supported and will give an NA p-value.

I think you are genuinely confusing outputs here. The first output block you show is the output from `summary.gam()`. The second output is from `gam.check()` (or `k.check()`) and these are not the same thing at all.

Comment: Hi :) Thank you for your reply. You are completely right, I found that the best way of performing the HGAM was by using ''' Yearf*Season ''' and not subsetting by Res. The year here is a factor.